# Counting words in a noncontinuous range in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need to count how many times a person's name appears in a noncontinuous range in excel. I used a formula on a different sheet that worked as it only looks at a column, but I need to look at different rows. I've tried giving the cells I need a named range and using that in the formula but it's return the `#VALUE` error.

[image: Example of rota]
[larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmx8w.png)

It's for a monthly rota where each week is on a new row. The There are also three activities each day. I use a summary table at the side to see how many times that month each person has done each activity. . I use the same sheet every month and just over write it, so it would be such a time saver if a formula automatically counted how many times each person did each activity.

Comment: What is the formula that is producing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Use a countif("range","name")


e.g. at N7 (count) for Claire:

=COUNTIF(A3:F22,M7)

where A3:F22 is all the data / all tables

and

where M7 is "Claire"

Comment: How do you account for placing the count into the columns (Person 1, Person 2 & Person 3) shown in the example?